# What is the measure word for a flag (on a pole/stick)?

Tags: counters

Let's say there is a building with six flags on the roof.

The flags are on small poles/sticks that can be carried by a person.

The rectangular flag itself makes me think of 枚 while the pole makes me think of 本.

Maybe there is a unique word for flags.

What is the appropriate measure word to use here ?

Comment: I thought this was a daft question, because clearly the flag is way more important than the pole. I was very wrong so +1: https://jisho.org/search/counter%20for%20flags

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks for the link, very useful for looking up counters.

Answer (score 3):

According to [数え方単位辞典](https://www.sanabo.com/kazoekata/ct_ha/ha/hata/), you can count it by　一本{いっぽん}、一枚{いちまい}、一流{ひとなが}れ、一旒{いちりゅう}、一棹{ひとさお}.

They also explain

> 旗はポールに掲げられると「本」で数えます。 1本のポールに複数の旗が掲げられた場合は「枚」で数えます。 古くは「流れ」「旒 (ç) 」「棹 (さお) 」などでも数えました。

If several flags on one pole, you can count 『枚』. Usually,『本』for one flag on one pole. I understand 棹{さお} for counting it, but hard to count by the other old format : 流{なが}れ, 旒{りゅう} since never seen them.